# $location from $exceptionHandler - dependency conflict

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, exceptionhandler

I'm trying to implement a very standard task: when an exception occurs, redirect to my `/error` page.

In a simplified form the code looks like this:

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$location', function($location) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
        $location.path("/error");
    };
}]);
```

However, AngularJS complains:
**Circular dependency found: $location <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope**

This looks like a fundamental limitation, not to allow use of `$location` when handling exceptions.

But how else can we do it then?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.$location), the only dependencies for `$location` are `$browser`, `$sniffer` and `$rootElement`.  I don't see why this code would throw this error... sorry, I'm not much help.  There must be some hidden dependency that isn't in the docs...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To get around this you need to call the `$injector` manually to resolve the dependency at runtime:

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', function($injector) {

    var $location;

    return function(exception, cause) {
        $location = $location || $injector.get('$location');
        $location.path("/error");
    };
}]);
```