# How to know when a dependency is available in angular

Tags: angularjs

Given the following, `$injector.get` will fail as `$rootScope` is not available.

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', $injector => {
  const $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')

  return (exception, cause) => {
    // code
  }
})
```

In researching, I keep coming across this, which works as it's resolved at runtime (when the inner function is called).

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', $injector => {
  return (exception, cause) => {
    const $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')
    // code
  }
})
```

What I'd like is to somehow know when I can resolve the dependency. Something like:

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', $injector => {
  $injector.illLetYouKnowWhenWeCanDoStuff().then(() => {
    const $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')
  })

  return (exception, cause) => {
    // code
  }
})
```

Is this possible?

related =>
[$location from $exceptionHandler - dependency conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554624/location-from-exceptionhandler-dependency-conflict)

Comment: Why do you inject the injector, instead of just injecting $rootScope in the first place? The injector would figure out the dependency, and thus create the $rootScope and inject it before creating your exceptionHandler. Also, note that the `$` prefix is precisely there to distinguish between angular services and your own services. So you shouldn't prefix your services with `$`.

Comment: @JBNizet read the q&a I've linked to at the bottom, and what service of mine are you referring to? the local $rootScope?

Comment: @JBNizet $injector is required for the second example to work (and my current workaround) but it's probably irrelevant in the first example (same error either way)

Comment: Ordinarily, all injectables that will ever be are available once the app bootstraps. New services are not generally added at runtime. Maybe if you explain at a higher level what you're trying to achieve, someone can help.

Comment: @JCFord Sure. I just need to get something from $rootScope inside this factory. Problem is it's not ready initially but I can get it after some period of time (ie inner function)

Comment: Not ready initially why? Loaded from asynchronously? From $http perhaps?

Comment: One thing you might consider is using `$rootScope.$broadcast` or `$scope.$emit` to send notification once your data is available.

Comment: @JCFord You can read the q&a I've linked to for an example of the problem, I'll admit I'm not exactly sure why it happens (though I get the same circular dependency)

Comment: @JCFord right but I need to be able to inject $rootScope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155348/discussion-between-jc-ford-and-aw04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All injectables registered through normal angular functions (factory, service, controller, etc) are available right away at bootstrap. `$rootScope` isn't registered normally. It's provided after the app bootstraps. Because `$exceptionHandler` is instantiated right away, `$rootScope` isn't available yet.

The best way to get around a circular dependency error is to break the circle. Let your `$exceptionHandler` depend on a custom service you build. Configure that new service in a `.run()` block into which `$rootScope` is injected.

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['myExceptionHandlingConfig', function(myExceptionHandlingConfig) {

  return function(exception, cause) {
    //do exceptional stuff
  }

}]);

app.factory('myExceptionHandlingConfig', function() {

  return {};

});

app.run(['$rootScope', 'myExceptionHandlingConfig', function($rootScope, myExceptionHandlingConfig){

  myExceptionHandlingConfig.someProperty = $rootScope.something;

}]);
```

Note: `$rootScope` will be pretty empty at bootstrap time, so you might want to set a `$watch` to update the service when whatever data you're looking for is available.